# Displaying time from date in ng-repeat Angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have following code trying to display time from a date

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items">
<input type="text" ng-model="item.name" />
<input ng-model="item.currentDate" />
</div>
```

The controller code is

```
function MyCtrl($scope, $filter) {
    $scope.item.currentDate = new Date();
    $scope.$watch('currentDate', function(date){
        $scope.currentDate = $filter('date')(date, 'shortTime');
    });
```

It doesnt work. I have a working plunker for the same code without ng-repeat in it.
http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/4108/

Please let me know how I can this filter to display time inside ng-repeat Thanks

Comment: define working? `currentDate` belongs to the `scope` in one example in your posted example it belongs an array of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you already have an array of items that you are looping over.  Something like this:

```
$scope.items = [{
    name: 'date1',
    currentDate: new Date()
}, {
    name: 'date2',
    currentDate: new Date()
}];
```

You need to setup your `$watch` on that array:

```
$scope.$watch('items', function (newValue, oldValue) {
    angular.forEach(newValue, function(item){
        item.currentDate = $filter('date')(item.currentDate, 'shortTime');
    });
}, true);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jerrade/UALXZ/)

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller you should setup an array of items:

```
 $scope.items = [];
 $scope.items.push({ name:'...', currentDate:new Date(...)});
```